# Can you recover sockets in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

I put a gem that I thought was a diamond in to my armor, and it was actually a topaz. Is there any way to get them out?

Answer (score 12):

To empty a socket in Diablo 2 LoD, there is the Horadric cube recipe:

> 1 Hel Rune + Scroll of Town Portal + Any Socketed Item = Remove items from sockets
>   Warning: This will destroy any gems, runes, or jewels you have socketed. This is useful if you are not happy with the gems you have socketed and you want to socket the item in another way.

If you want to remove your diamond from the socket (and thus destroy it) and replace it with a topaz, you can do it but the cost (Hel rune) is probably not worth it unless the armor is particularly valuable and you intend to use it for a while.

This recipe isn't present in Diablo 2 Classic, which doesn't have runes or socketed armor, so presumably you are talking about D2 LoD and not Classic (aka non-expansion.)

Comment: Definitely agree with this post... if you are not familiar with the game, Hel is a pretty high tier rune, not something you want to just waste. I would not bother unless the armor is worth using in Hell difficulty.

Comment: Of course if the armor is junk, it's not worth using an Hel rune. But Hel is not very valuable nor rare either. Better spend an Hel to be happy with your item than hoard it.

Answer (score -1):

**Diablo 2 offered no way to recycle a weapon or piece of armor**. There is no way to remove a socket without the use of an unofficial mod or save editor.

If you are playing with a local character, I would consider simply using a character editor. It has been a long time since I played, but I remember there being a few good programs with a lot of customisation. You might have to re-generate the gemstones and the armor.

This feature was only brought in with Diablo 3, where if you salvaged an item with something in it's socket, the socket item will be returned to the player at the expense of destroying the main item.

Comment: in D3 you can also remove gems from sockets via the Jeweler who will save the item and gem for a fee of gold.

Comment: Can you confirm this? I had a big problem in Diablo 3 where I lost an important jewel assuming the same thing. The jewel crafter automatically opens the socket, but destroys the item that was in the socket, on the Xbox version.

Comment: @Timelord64 You went to the Blacksmith and broke down your equipment. If you went to the Jeweler you can pay gold to unsocket your item.

Comment: No.. I went to the jewel crafter. I didn't even know you could salvage until I looked it up for OP

Comment: @Timelord64 I'm certain that on D3:ROS for ps4 at least (but this should be true for all versions of the game: http://i.imgur.com/J2mUnLq.png), the gem goes back to your inventory into the 'gems' pocket, perhaps if your bags are full, the gem will actually drop on the ground, maybe you lost it this way?

Comment: No. Definitely not. I was very careful.. had a glitch and received a massive OP jewel. Never mind. Might be a bug or console difference. I managed to recover an old save regardless